# GC operations in Visual Studio Unit Testing

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, garbage-collection

I've observed that if you do a `GC.Collect()` in a TestMethod, the test is interrupted and appears as aborted. Why is that?

I need to do a:

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

In order to see if the GC is throwing an exception in the finalizer method when I forgot to dispose my classes. How can I do it?

Cheers.

Comment: Can't reproduce. The following code works fine `[TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1() {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }`

Comment: Did some finilizer perhaps throw an Exception?

Comment: Indeed. I was expecting an error in the test, but I got the exception in the test summary and I didn't realise it. Sorry about that. Steven post an answer and I will mark it :)

Comment: The issue is: The finalizers run on another thread. So when a exception happens, it isn't thrown on the 'test'-thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Steven pointed out, the problem was an exception in the finalizer.